# Summernote - How do you set the data container for the popovers?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, summernote

Im using summernote (https://github.com/summernote/summernote)

Is there a way to set the popovers, tooltips etc that are working along with bootstrap to be inside a container instead of the `body`?

I can see someone already mentioned the problem, but not the solution.
https://github.com/summernote/summernote/pull/2036

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I have got a tricked solution myself, still it would be great if summernote actually do it themselves.

```
//Wrap popovers into a container
$('.popover.bottom').ready(function(){
    $('.popover.bottom').wrapAll('<div class="exit_container" />');
});
```

However, since tooltips are dynamically created, its not possible to do this with that.